# Where to submit fixes and ideas to the Chromium project?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Yes, it is open source but in a way Google develops it behind closed doors then release it to the public. You really not have much to say about what goes into the product, right? Where to submit important fixes?

Edit: what if my submission is rather an idea for a feature that something the developers might call an actual bug?

[Self-reference](https://superuser.com/questions/537090/prevent-chromium-performing-a-search-when-typing-in-address-bar-and-pressing-ctr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have found a bug then submit it: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

More details and options are http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Answer (score 0):

As Posted by Dave Rook, bugs go at - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

There are discussion groups available for suggestions to the project here - http://www.chromium.org/developers/discussion-groups